# Content Security Policy error in ASP.net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, content-security-policy

we are trying to implement CSP in asp.net forms. Adding all the hash to CSP header resolves most of the issues. But we are facing some inline style issues.
In aspx page we have label like shown below
[image]

```
 <asp:Login ID="UserLogin" runat="server" class="loginControl" 
 FailureText="Email address or password is incorrect." OnLoggedIn="AfterLogin"
 OnLoginError="OnLoginError"
 MembershipProvider="SqlProvider">
 <LayoutTemplate>
     <div class="error">
         <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
     </div>
     <div class="login">
         <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="fontbold">Email:</asp:Label><br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ValidationGroup="UserLogin" ToolTip="Email is required." ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ControlToValidate="UserName">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </div>
     <div class="login">
         <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" Font-Bold="True">Password:</asp:Label><br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" Width="180px" TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ValidationGroup="UserLogin" ToolTip="Password is required." ErrorMessage="Password is required." ControlToValidate="Password">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </div>
     <div class="login">
         <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" ValidationGroup="UserLogin" CommandName="Login" Text="Sign In" />
     </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
```

</asp:Login>

But in runtime, .net injects some styles which is not available in code, which throws CSP violation
[image]

```
 <table id="UserLogin" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="loginControl" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>
                            <div class="error">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="login">
                                <label for="UserLogin_UserName" id="UserLogin_UserNameLabel" class="fontbold">Email:</label><br />
                                <input name="UserLogin$UserName" type="text" id="UserLogin_UserName" style="width:180px;" />
                                <span id="UserLogin_UserNameRequired" title="Email is required." style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="login">
                                <label for="UserLogin_Password" id="UserLogin_PasswordLabel" style="font-weight:bold;">Password:</label><br />
                                <input name="UserLogin$Password" type="password" id="UserLogin_Password" style="width:180px;" />
                                <span id="UserLogin_PasswordRequired" title="Password is required." style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="login">
                                <input type="submit" name="UserLogin$LoginButton" value="Sign In" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;UserLogin$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;UserLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="UserLogin_LoginButton" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
</tr>
```

We are no interested to add unsafe-inline. Please suggest if any other solution.
Thanks

We tried to create separate css with this styles, but still in runtime, these styles are getting appended

Comment: *".net injects some styles which is not available in code"* - didn't you just set `Font-Bold="True"`? anyway, please post code as texts not images. the light theme hurts my eyes.

Comment: Thanks @BagusTesa. I got a clue from your reply. I think we have to remove all these attributes to style and then apply the css. It can remove the CSP violations. Let me try that.

Comment: @BagusTesa, sorry for the confusion. I have added the code and edited the question. You can see asp:Label changes to table and some extra styles.another example is asp:RequiredFieldValidator. All these creates CSP violations. Do you have any idea on this. Thanks

Comment: `Width="180px"` translates to inline css. [tag:webform] is made before CSP a thing so keep in mind that there are tons of properties that emit inline css.. sorry, i can't find exhaustive list of the properties to watch for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are totally out of luck in terms of achieving no inline styles. Even modern frameworks usually struggle to work correctly without them.

I realise that the OP said not interested in `unsafe-inline` so I feel it is really important to emphasise the distinction between a blanket `default-src 'unsafe-inline';` which allows injected JavaScript and the potential total site compromise that comes with it, and the proposed styles only solution which in some small number of cases might lead to some information leakage - there is a good post [here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/) explaining this.

A Content Security Policy of `default-src 'self' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;` or similar will only allow `unsafe-inline` for your styles whilst still protecting you from the vast majority of issues.